# Why aren't more physicists trying to reproduce a surprising experiment about the relation between QM and gravitomagnetism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, superconductivity

In [this](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2006/03/060325232140.htm) article an experiment is described which shows an unusual behavior of gravitomagnetism around an accelerated spinning, superconducting ring. The gravitomagnetic field was many orders higher than what General Relativity predicted it to be. The experimenters have done the experiment over and over (about 250 times, as one can read in the article) again, discussed the results over and over, looked for errors in whatever you can think of, and published their result 8 months after all this was done. I don't agree with the explanation (which is copied from a conjectured effect in low energy physics, i.e. photons that become massive), but that plays no role. I just wondered why other experimenters didn't do any follow-up experiments. The claim which followed from the experiments is not one to be wiped under the carpet. Isn't the connection between gravity and superconduction (which is a connection between gravity and QM) taken seriously in the physics community? Is the experiment considered as a fraud? And if so, why don't try to reproduce it?

Comment: Three reasons: 1. they couldn't get funding to redo the experiment, 2.  redoing the experiment wouldn't help them get funding, 3. a novel experiment to show this effect was do difficult to do.

Answer (score 5):

Let's review the history of this. In 1989, Tate presented surprising experimental findings. Your hyperlink, a conference presentation it mentions by Tajmar and de Matos, and a [this paper of theirs](https://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0607/0607086.pdf) attempting a theoretical explanation, all date to 2006. That paper has been cited [14 times](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cites=571242163928537800&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=1,5&hl=en). This includes a [2007](https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/0707/0707.3806v5.pdf)  paper (co-authored by Tajmar) finding an effect too large for general relativity to explain, [another 2007 paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0707/0707.3806.pdf) (also co-authored by Tajmar) that rules out a number of alternative theories, [a 2007/8 paper by Bambi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2042.pdf) explaining how neutron-star physics constrains the potential new physics, a [2008](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921453407013937)  experiment not involving Tajmar or de Matos that showed the effect is much smaller than they predicted, a [2011](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Martin_Tajmar/publication/231030072_Evaluation_of_enhanced_frame-dragging_in_the_vicinity_of_a_rotating_niobium_superconductor_liquid_helium_and_a_helium_superfluid/links/55aa16d908ae481aa7f99caa.pdf)  Tajmar paper constraining the potential new physics even further, and a [2012](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=YafxlC5hL0UC&oi=fnd&pg=PA132&ots=bjW1C0K6it&sig=Z3VDTgiQosab8VLHjPnxs15KmIU) literature review of the problem. So many physicists have worked on this in recent years both empirically and theoretically.